# Python typing hints subtype

Tags: python, mypy, typing

I have an object of the type `Dict[str, Union[str, Dict[str, str]]]`, which is being appended into a Python list of type `List[Dict[str, Union[str, Dict[str, Optional[Union[str, bool]]]]]]`. Mypy raises an error for this.

I realize that this is Mypy not accepting `str` as being part of `Optional[Union[str, bool]]`. Is there some workaround to this?

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal, reproducible example?

Comment: Unions of dissimilar types like `Union[str, Dict[str, str]]` are generally a "code smell" of something that is not a good design.  But in the case of dict values, if you're trying to say that "some key's value is always `str` and other key's value is always `Dict[str, str]`" then you would be better off using either `Dict[str, Any]` or a `TypedDict`.  When you say `Dict[str, Union[...]]` it's saying that _all_ the values really have that union type, which is maybe not what you really want.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict lets you specify specific type for each key's value, at the cost that you should have a known, fixed set of keys

Comment: This is because [`dict` and `list` are invariant](https://blog.daftcode.pl/covariance-contravariance-and-invariance-the-ultimate-python-guide-8fabc0c24278). You cannot, say, append `dict[str, str]` to `list[dict[str, str | int]]`.

Comment: @Anentropic the type I'm using here is to annotate an incoming payload, so I'm not sure if a "code smell" is avoidable. I'm trying to avoid using `Any`, since that just prevents Mypy from type-checking the values in the `Dict`.

Comment: If the structure of the payload is known, it might be cleaner to define a `TypeDict` instead. As you have the ability to define a heterogeneous `dict` which might just supersede the need to use `Union` here.